# How to set default expand in a q-table?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I copied the code from "expanded rows" "Treats".
https://quasar.dev/vue-components/table

Is there a way to set the first row as default expand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do that.

You can pass `expanded` prop in `q-table` or can use `v-model:expanded="expandedRows"` if want to sync expanded rows.

```
<q-table
    ref="mytable"
    :expanded="expandedRows"
    ...
>
</q-table>
```

and define `expandedRows` ref with key of first row in setup.

```
const expandedRows = ref(["key-of-first-row"]);
```

and second way is with `setExpanded` method.

```
  const mytable = ref(null);

  onMounted(function () {
    mytable.value.setExpanded(["key-of-first-row"])
  })
```

> Note:- When you ask any question in any forums, always put the code you have tried.